# How to find websites to help 5 year olds to learn to read

Tags: reading

What are the primary ways I could search for websites which contain stories suitable for five year old children learning to read?

I've tried using phrases like "Children learning to read stories" and similar keywords but I usually end up at sites which have mostly games or videos - neither of which I am looking for.

So, does anyone know how to find sites which contain stories to help young children learn to read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching hundreds of websites, I finally found one that has what I was looking for. It is [here](http://www.oxfordowl.co.uk/Teacher).

They have books which you can sort by age and reading level. The books are made in flash but you can print them out, which is exactly what I wanted.

Best of all, the books are free. Yeah!

The search string was: [ebook children stories](http://www.google.com/search?q=ebook%20children%20stories)

Comment: That's terrific. Do you remember how you found it?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me....the answer should answer the question which was about the search criteria. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when you are looking for downloadable/printable files, if you append your search with *filetype:pdf* it will get you what you want. In this case, that yielded documents that were about the search terms (I used *children's stories*) rather than example of children's stories. I redid the search with *[children's stories .pdf](https://www.google.com/search?q=children%27s%20stories%20filteype%3a.pdf&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#client=firefox-a&hs=tjG&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=children%27s%20stories%20.pdf&oq=children%27s%20stories%20.pdf&gs_l=serp.3..0i30j0i7i30l2j0i30.33979.35498.2.38342.9.9.0.0.0.0.139.1074.0j9.9.0...0.0...1c.1.17.psy-ab.f5yTwr4W7u8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47883778,d.dmQ&fp=413195408aebdc26&biw=1366&bih=638)*, and I think I got closer to what you were looking for, which is sites of children stories that are being delivered in pdf format. You could redo the search with other terms and include the ".pdf" and perhaps get additional results. Pdf files are printable through Adobe's free software.

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm having trouble just finding the right sites.

Comment: Did you click on the link? There are several sites on just the first page of results with downloadable books - one site has 783 links (not all kids' books, but many) for downloadable books.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying (I missed the link before). Unfortunately, I'm only finding low quality stories (witches eating children, animals with birth defects, etc.). I'm sure they intend to teach non-discrimination but I'm really wanted to keep it light to start the reading process.

Comment: Many American libraries provide access to Tumblebooks through their websites. Perhaps you have access to this or a similar online service through your library.

Comment: I am traveling overseas and not much of a library system where I am.

Comment: Don't know if this is a possibility, but if you have a permanent home in the States, you may be able to get a library card from your home library (if you don't already have one). My kid is at school overseas and can access our library resources here.

Answer (score 0):

Show her these videos: http://www.youtube.com/user/letterpeopleland

Kindergarten teachers used to use this show from the early 70s to about the mid 90s to help kids with reading

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for something I can print out to read on paper.